# Find a string of multiplicy length

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I have to find every word whose length is a multiple of 7 and less than 35. I can use some pattern like

```
/\b([a-zA-Z0-9]{7}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{21}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{28})\b/
```

but I hope that there's some better solution like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{7|14|21|28}
```

or even like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{7*k}
```

Comment: Use one to five repeats of a group of exactly seven characters.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't get it, could you write a code example?

Comment: Like what @bro has just written as an answer.   I'd rather not type regexes on an iPad keyboard; it is painful.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use a regex here? I would definitely use `String#scan` or `#split` if this is not an assignment

Comment: @floum sorry for my stupid question, I am newbie, but these methods use regex, doesn't they?

Comment: @Ed : Sorry, you're right, the result is just really easier to understand imho. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
/\b(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}){1,5}\b/
```

which matches strings of length 7,14,21,28,35

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eO4oG3/2

EDIT: Another possibility would be using backreferences
http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with words of length 14, besides the first instance

Answer (score 2):

This one should work:

```
\b([[:alnum:]]{7}){1,5}\b
```

It matches every character of the class `[A-Za-z0-9]`, every sub-word of `length 7` and its product with `5`.

e.g.

```
12345672234567
abcdefghijklmn
```

but not `12345678`

**EDIT**
Replaced the \w with [[:alnum]] as this POSIX class contains only letters and digits.

Comment: \w also contains underscore _  http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: What is the benefit of the question mark?  Does it work the same if you omit it?

Comment: yep, the ? is not needed here, my bad, I take it out.
with the underscore, i did not know :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you break words on non-word character (use `String#split` if breaking on spaces) :

```
text.scan(/\w+/).select { |word| [7, 14, 21, 28].include?(word.size) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way, and the closest you can get using regex.

`(?i)\b(?=[a-z\d]{1,34}\b)(?:[a-z\d]{7})+\b`

Below:  `'34'` is max length variable, `'7'` is the multiple factor variable.
They are independent of one another.
You *can* construct this at runtime with any length and multiplicity variable values.

```
 (?i)                         # No case
 \b                           # Word boundary
 (?= [a-z\d]{1,34} \b )       # Max length = 34
 (?: [a-z\d]{7} )+            # Multiple factor = 7
 \b                           # Word boundary
```

Input:

```
length=7  aaaaaaa   
length=14 bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
length=21 ccccccccccccccccccccc
length=28 dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
length=35 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 10 , len 7 ) 
aaaaaaa  

-------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 32 , len 14 ) 
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb  

-------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 58 , len 21 ) 
ccccccccccccccccccccc  

-------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 91 , len 28 ) 
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```